# How to map a result in a promise that comes from a function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, mapping

I have this function that returns a result from a GET in an API (I am using an AWS Rest API, for contextualization):

```
const listUsers = async () => {
  const apiName = 'AdminQueries'
  const path = '/listUsers'
  const params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession())
        .getAccessToken()
        .getJwtToken()}`,
    },
  }
  return await API.get(apiName, path, params)
}
```

And if i call the function to print on console, like:

`console.log(listUsers())`

I get an array on my console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
Users: Array(42)
0: {Username: "00e534e3-08ee-4bc1-9d19-ab18208e3f94", Attributes: Array(5), UserCreateDate: "2021-09-06T10:05:35.537Z", UserLastModifiedDate: "2021-09-06T10:05:35.537Z", Enabled: true, …}
1: {Username: "05f4ce2e-4b57-48d5-9f5f-e18d250aefb4", Attributes: Array(6), UserCreateDate: "2021-09-10T19:45:32.002Z", UserLastModifiedDate: "2021-09-10T19:54:37.333Z", Enabled: true, …}
2: {Username: "06a78cc7-af6a-4fb6-975d-458c089b69a5", Attributes: Array(6), UserCreateDate: "2021-09-10T18:04:27.780Z", UserLastModifiedDate: "2021-09-10T18:04:27.780Z", Enabled: true, …}
3: {Username: "32652d77-e7a4-444a-9995-f8f50eb14633", Attributes: Array(6), UserCreateDate: "2021-09-06T15:48:24.897Z", UserLastModifiedDate: "2021-09-06T15:49:39.476Z", Enabled: true, …}
length: 42
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

How do i map these users to show in an array? I tried but couldn't.

Comment: It's an async function use `console.log(await listUsers())`

Comment: Remove `async` and `await` in your `listUsers` function; you don't need it there. Now run `const users = await listUsers();` and `console.log(users)` from some async function. (to be clear: there's no escaping back to sync code; once you use async code, you stay async as you go up the function calls) also see here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kpj204wL/

Comment: @ChrisG if i remove the async await on the function body, it brokes it, cause the `.getAccessToken()` depends on it.

Also i don't get how this solves my problem. I still can't map it...

Comment: @AnkushVerma if i do that, i get

`Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)`

Comment: Right; I missed the 2nd await. Anyway, if you call `listUsers()` in a sync context, you will always get the promise, not the users array. You need to `await listUsers()` to get the array. You can use `await` in the top-level but you have to enable it or update node. Did you look at my fiddle...? It should make all of this clear.

Comment: @ChrisG as i said in the above comment, still doesn't work. I get that error.

I am on React (actually NextJS), on a company-wide project, how could i enable this thing? I am not getting, actually.

Comment: Also note that this is the #1 beginner's JavaScript issue, which is why this exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listUsers function is returning a promise. To get the response you can make use of something like this

```
const listUsers = async () => {
  const apiName = 'AdminQueries'
  const path = '/listUsers'
  const params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession())
        .getAccessToken()
        .getJwtToken()}`,
    },
  }
  return await API.get(apiName, path, params)
}

**** update ****
const func = async () => {
   const response = await listUsers();
   console.log(response);
}

func();
```

Comment: Yes! This way i get an Array on the console.

But i can't do func().map, or func.map. So how would i map it?

Comment: In that case, you can simply return your array instead of returning promise from `listUsers` function.

Comment: but which array, man? i am not getting...

if i call func(), this appears on the console: i.imgur.com/TB9O6tK.png

If i don't call func(), it doesn't appear. But how can i show THIS array in my react component? I am not getting, you know?

Comment: since you wanted to use map, i assumed api responds with an array. if its correct, you can setState inside listUsers(),

Answer (score 1):

```
const listUsers = async () => {
      const apiName = 'AdminQueries'
      const path = '/listUsers'
      const params = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession())
            .getAccessToken()
            .getJwtToken()}`,
        },
      }
      return await API.get(apiName, path, params)
    }

    const func = async () => {
      const response = await listUsers();
      reponse.data?.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
      })
    }
```

Comment: `TypeError: response.map is not a function`